# How do you resize an existing vector mask in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, resize, cs6

I have created a vector mask for a layer in Photoshop containing a circle. Now I would like to fine-tune its position and size. I can only move individual or multiple anchor points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to transform. Scaling is one of the basic transformation tools.

Comment: `Strg` + `Alt` + `T` has done the job. Thank You. (certainly a beginner's question, I know)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize/move the vector mask you have created, and you are able to select multiple anchor points, you can:
Press shift and select all the anchor points and move them together.

Answer (score 1):

first off, all the responses above are incorrect...

**YOU NEED TO UNLINK THE vector mask and the layer OBJECT... THEN YOU CAN CMD + T, free transform.**

Comment: Please do not cry (capital letters)! And the proof that the other answers are incorrect? Without a proof this is better a comment, not an answer, I guess ...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to first unlink the vector mask and the layer object, by clicking the chain icon shown below.  Then you can use the methods suggested by the other answers.

[image: linked mask]
[image: unlicked mask]